# Referencing mcexam.sty

Tags: paths

I would like to make my version of `mcexam.sty` available to all my mcexam files without having to have mcexam.sty in every folder.  For example, I may have an exam document in the following locations:

```
c:\documents\course1\exam1
c:\documents\course2\exam2
```

and these two exams may be synchronized with my NAS on

```
\\NASC12345\documents\exam1
\\NASC12345\documents\exam2
```

I know I could put mcexam.sty in a directory:

`c:\documents\latexstyle\mcexam.sty`

then use the code:

```
    \usepackage{c:/documents/latexdstyle/mcexam}
```

But this solution would work only on one computer and not on synchronized devices.  For example, the previous c: location may be synchronized on another device:

`\\NASC12345\documents\latexstyle\mcexam.sty`

But this synchronized file would not be read by the `LaTeX` document.  Is there a way to reference the style file using a relative parent directory such as the /documents/ directory?

---

The style file that should be edited is located here in Windows 10:

```
...AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex\latex\mcexam
```

The location of the style file will be in different locations for different O/S.

Comment: It sounds like the package isn't properly installed. There should be no need to put it in every directory.

Comment: Maybe I did install it correctly at first then. The package seemed to be working fine without the style file in every directory. Now I'm trying to change the style file to add space between MC answers. This change works as long as I have the style file in the same directory. Without the edited style file in the same directory it reverts back to the original style.